# How to make a many to many relationship in core data in the .xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nsentitydescription

Hi guys really need help with the example below for core data - objective-C IOS

Entity1: Person
Attribute: Name

Entity2: Languages
Attribute: LanguageName

Example would be Name: John can speak LanguageName: English, Korean, Japanese

Example 2 would be LanguageName: Spanish, English, Korean is spoken by John, Amy, Ashley

First question is how do I make that relationship in the the xcdatamodel?

Second question is how to store that e.g. John speaks English, Korean, Japanese into the core data?

Third is how do I show that Data dynamically e.g

Say if I have a button that is generated by the languageName and when I click on it should display everyone who speaks that language in a tableview?

I have tried a different approach using bit shifting the and storing the sports in each bit and using a while loop to match it but I have been reading a while now and a many to many relationship seem to be more suitable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

I didn't provide any code because I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a many-to-many relationship, you create two to-many relationships and make them the inverse of each other.

In your case, you can

1. Add a `speaks` relationship to `Person`, and

   - Set `destination` to `Language`
   - Set `type` to `To Many`
2. Add a `spokenBy` relationship to `Language`, and

   - Set `destination` to `Person`
   - Set `inverse` to `speaks`
   - Set `type` to `To Many`

By correctly setting the `inverse`, you can set the relationship from one side and Core Data will automatically take care of another side thus ensuring data consistency. For example, *Mandy* can speak English and Spanish. To save the languages she speaks into your Core Data store, simply do the following:

```
// mandy, english and spanish are all NSManagedObject objects
mandy.speaks = [NSSet setWithObjects:english, spanish, nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [english.spokenBy containsObject:mandy] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // YES
```

You can listen to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` to get notified whenever your managed objects are changed (i.e., inserted, deleted or updated).

---

Refer to this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW8) for more info.